SSIS Dynamic column mapping for increasing columns
I have an Excel sheet that I need to import to SQL Server database.
The problems I am facing is that columns of the sheet keep increasing every time I do an import.
I need a dynamic solution where every time I do an import, the previous table gets dropped and recreated with the new set of columns.
I hope someone has a solution for this.
I am working on a script with the help of GPT, but it is not working.

SSIS Data Flow Tasks require the data sources and destination to be strictly defined; it does not allow for columns to be dynamic. You'll need to use a Script Task for this, or something else entirely.
